# SQL Union query error

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to join two count querys

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM clients WHERE addedby = 1
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS converts FROM clients WHERE addedby = 1 AND status = '6'
```

What this returns is

```
total
4
0
```

this is the correct data, what I was expecting was this

```
total     converts
  4           0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `UNION` query to do this. [`SELECT A UNION SELECT B`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) returns the rows of `A` followed by the rows of `B` (deduplicated; if you want *all* rows from both datasets, use `UNION ALL`).

What you want is something like this:

```
select 
    (select count(*) from clients where addedby=1) as total,
    (select count(*) from clients where addedby=1 and status='6') as converts
```

Other way to do this is using a `case ... end` expression that returns `1` if `status='6'`:

```
select 
    count(*) from clients, 
    sum(case when status='6' then 1 else 0 end) as converts
from clients
```

Answer (score 2):

No `UNION` needed, do it in one pass.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total,
       SUM(CASE status WHEN '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as converts
FROM clients;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to write this query is as a conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) as total, sum(status = '6') as converts
from cleints
where addedby = 1;
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers with `1` being true and `0` being false.  You can just sum of the values to get a count.